# How do I remove the prompt to save information on clipboard?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that allows me to select a file and then copies a range from that file and pasted it into the target worksheet. However every time I do this is opens the source file and then closes which prompts me if I want to save the information on the clip board.

I don't know if it would be better to just copy the data without opening the source excel.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DCDatabaseCopy()
Dim vFile As Variant
Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
Dim DCRowCount As Integer

Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet

    '-------------------------------------------------------------
    'Open file with data to be copied

    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.*)," & "*.*", 1, "Select Excel File", "Open", False)

    'If Cancel then Exit
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
    Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
    Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)
    End If

    '--------------------------------------------------------------
    'Copy Range
    DCRowCount = wsCopyFrom.Range("A1", wsCopyFrom.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    wsCopyFrom.Range("A1:G" & DCRowCount).Copy
    wsCopyTo.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
            Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    'Close file that was opened
    wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you close the workbook run:

```
wbCopyFrom.Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

This will clear the clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

use these 2 lines of code before and after, it will bypass the clipboard prompt

```
Application.DiplayAlerts = FALSE
Application.DiplayAlerts = TRUE
```

Or it could be that you need to use this:

```
ActiveWindow.Close savechanges:=FALSE
```

Obviously if the file is not in the ActiveWindow then replace that part of the code with wherver it is

Comment: First will bypass **all** promts not only the clipboard prompt. Second is what he already does in his last line. You just need to exit the CutCopyMode before closing.